# Range-for loops not using std::next by default?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am surprised that by default a range-based for loop is missing the customization point of calling `std::next` on the iterator returned by `std::begin` and is instead directly calling `operator++()`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Iterator {
    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
        ++i;
        return *this;
    }

    int operator*()
    {
        return i;
    }

    int i;
};

bool operator!=(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs)
{
    return lhs.i != rhs.i;
}

Iterator& next(Iterator& it)
{
    // this is where I need to injext my code :/
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    return ++it;
}

struct Container {

    Iterator begin() { return { 0 }; }
    Iterator end() { return { 10 }; }
};

int main()
{
    Container con;

    for (const auto& elem : con) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea why this decision has been made? And any idea how could I inject my code right before every call to `operator++()` then?

Comment: All iterators are required allow `++it` so `next` is an unneeded abstraction.

Comment: I dont really understand the question. You seem to have already a solution to do what you want in `operator++` ...

Comment: @NathanOliver why unneeded? is a zero cost abstraction that could have been used as a customization point

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 because I am providing the full code to make things clearer, but I actually cannot modify the operator++ itself since is third party stuff

Comment: A function call is not zero cost.  *why unneeded?* Because ranged based for loops were built to use iterators and all iterators are required to support `++it`.

Comment: @NathanOliver it has indeed zero cost if it is inlined and by default calling `operator++`, there would be no different in the generated assembly between calling `std::next` or calling `operator++` directly.

Comment: Sure, if it is inlined.  There is no guarantee that it will be though.

Comment: what is the actual goal of this? I mean you can do whatever you want to add in `next` in the last line of the loop, I know its not what you want, but what exactly do you want?

Comment: @NathanOliver any decent compiler is basically doing that already for `std::begin` and `std::end`, I still see this as a missing customization point for no good reason. There are popular talks around like "free your functions" by Klaus Iglberger, and then the standard is by default calling a member operator? I do not get it.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 `std::begin` and `std::end` are not used, unless the range is not an array and does not provide member begin and end.  If it is a container then `begin` and `end` are called directly.  This goes along perfectly with why `next`/`advance` is not used.  This is supposed to fast as possible and an extra function call could make it slower.

Comment: @NathanOliver Let's not pretend the standard cares about debug build performance. Most of this stuff is zero cost abstraction under optimizations, but I disagree that "it might not be optimized away even though it is trivial" is a successful argument for or against any of the iterator abstractions or `std::next`.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 If you cannot modify `operator++` for a type that is not yours then it would also not be "correct" to use `std::next` as customization point for it. It's not your type, so it's not yours to specialize operations for. Unlike messing with `namespace std` in the wrong way it wouldn't be straight up UB, but it's definitely fragile and bad practice.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right and my assumption was definitely wrong: by default, range-for-loop will look for member function `.begin()` and `.end()` and only in case they are not found it will look for free functions. But I do not think this design choice has anything to do with performances.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why this decision has been made?

Nope.

> And any idea how could I inject my code right before every call to operator++() then?

You can write a container wrapper that has a `begin` and `end` that returns some wrapped iterator, that decorates the `operator++`. It requires lots of boiler plate, and to be honest I am not sure if it is worth the effort when you can achieve the same effect with a non-range-based loop and zero boilerplate. Anyhow here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
template <typename C,typename F>
struct container_wrapper {
    template <typename iterator>
    struct iterator_wrapper {
        iterator base;
        F func;
        typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type operator*() { 
             return *base;
        }
        iterator_wrapper& operator++() {
            func();
            ++base;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator !=(const iterator_wrapper& other) { 
             return base != other.base; 
        }
    };
    C& container;
    F func;
    iterator_wrapper<typename C::iterator> begin() { return iterator_wrapper<typename C::iterator>{ container.begin(),func }; }
    iterator_wrapper<typename C::iterator> end() { return iterator_wrapper<typename C::iterator> { container.end(),func }; }
};

template <typename C,typename F>
container_wrapper<C,F> make_container_wrapper(C& c, F f) { return {c,f}; }

int main(){
    std::vector<int> x{ 1,2,3,4,5,6};
    for (const auto& x : make_container_wrapper(x,[](){std::cout << "\n";})) {
        std::cout << x;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

You can pass a lambda as second parameter that is executed before incrementing.

PS: The above should work in C++11, while in newer standards it might be a tiny bit simpler (eg you wouldnt need a `make_..` helper function for deduction).

Comment: Doesn't this (sadly) need like 20 more lines of boilerplate iterator facade? Not faulting you for not reciting that incantation here, but it should probably be mentioned more explicitly...

Comment: @MaxLanghof sry,  don't understand what you mean. Its only meant to be used inside the range based for loop,  where nobody gets to see the iterators. No,  actually it is meant to demonstrate that it requires too much boilerplate the be really useful in practice;)

Comment: Well someone might try and use this with a `std::algorithm` (why not?), in which case the lack of iterator tags and such might be problematic. But true, if we assume that it'll only ever be used in a range-for, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why this decision has been made?

Because forward iterators need to implement `operator++(int)` and `operator++()` properly. It's in the standard, that's what makes a forward iterator, well, a forward iterator. `std::next` is not a customization point. It provides an alternative way of getting a new instance of the pseudo-iterator object, usually when the pseudo-iterator either is not a class, or doesn't provide operators, or has no methods, etc. If the "pseudo"-iterator object type itself provides the increment operator, then it cannot be safely treated like a pseudo-iterator. It must either adhere to the contract of the relevant iterator, or you must not use it like it was an iterator: **it isn't!** Instead, provide a wrapper. Merely providing `next` as a "customization" is likely not enough, so the design prevents you from assuming that it's enough: you have to do more work anyway, since you need to examine the pseudo-iterator object's API to wrap it.

> And any idea how could I inject my code right before every call to operator++() then?

Use your own iterators. They can wrap whatever pseudo-iterator object is provided by the third-party library you're using.

The main problem with such customization points is that not only range-for would be using them, so whatever side effects you wish to add for the purpose of range-for, will break other things, and quite possibly you'll have large projects with hundreds of latent bugs that way, and unrelated changes will make the whole thing blow up.

The wrapper class should provide the functionality that's needed, and then if some new use case comes up, it won't compile, and the wrapper will have to be extended. This way the latent bugs won't be a problem (assuming that you have sufficient coverage in the unit tests for the wrapper).

It's clear that whatever the third-party object returns as its "iterator" is not really the iterator you want. Thus wrap it so that it works for you. It's really easy.

Answer (score 0):

The range-based for loop does not use function next.

It is defined the following way

```
{
    auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
    auto __begin = begin-expr ;
    auto __end = end-expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
            statement
    }
}
```

The general function `std::next` does not return a reference to the source iterator

```
template <class InputIterator>
constexpr InputIterator next(InputIterator x,
                             typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type n = 1);
```

Its usage is the same as

> 6 Effects: Equivalent to: advance(x, n); return x;

Using this function the loop would look like

```
for ( ; __begin != __end; __begin = next( __begin ) )
```

that produces a redundant code.

As for the general functions std::next and std::prev then they are intentially designed to create a new iterator without changing the original iterator.

Consider for example the following if statement

```
if ( *current == *std::next( current ) ) /*...*/;
```

If the function `std::next` would return a reference to the original iterator then the if expression had undefined behavior.

Comment: The question is why?  This doesn't answer that

Comment: This is clear in the question as well, but why should not take advantage since `std::next` is in STL as well? It is indeed using `std::begin` and `std::end`, why not `std::next`?

Comment: Now I am commenting your updated answer: yes, indeed `std::next` is doing redundant stuff, but it has been introduced together with the range based for loop in C++11, I still see both (1) no reason why `std::next` signature is done that way (compared for example to `std::advance` which is way more generic) and still (2) why it is then not used by default.